# Comparing fs.readdirSync to what should be the same fs.readdirSync on MacOS vs Windows

Tags: node.js, json, windows, macos, special-characters

Unexpected behavior when comparing two folders containing the same filenames on MacOS. On windows the comparison works. On MacOS .includes is never true.

Steps to reproduce:

1. Create 2 separate folders with filenames containing special characters ä, ö, ü.
   for example:

   *'Aktivität.json',
   'Anfängerin.json',
   'Arbeitsgerät.json',
   'Augenhöhle.json',
   'Ausländer.json',
   'Ängstlichkeit.json',
   'Ärger.json',
   'Ärztin.json',
   'Bankdrücken.json',
   'Bauchspeicheldrüse.json',
   'Bäckerei.json'*
2. Create and run node script:

```
   

     import fs from "fs";
        var dir = "../path/";
        var path = `${dir}folder1/`;
        var files = await fs.readdirSync(path);
        var pathDone = `${dir}folder2/`;
        var filesDone = await fs.readdirSync(pathDone);
        console.log(files.length,filesDone.length)
        files = files.filter((val) =>( !filesDone.includes(val)&&val.includes('.json')));
        console.log(files)
        console.log(filesDone)
```

I know it must be to do with how the filenames are encoded, but why would be comparing the two with the same filenames not work?

Comment: What are the contents of each folder? Is it the same files in both folders? Also: What is getting logged?

Comment: So this is the strangest thing. The output that I am getting is that files that seem to have the same name don't match between the two folders. If I create the files on this Mac computer they match. If I copy the same file from my original directory into the two folders they match. I moved the code and files to another directory and the same error occurs but after I commit it to github and download it again the error is gone. So I could solve this by creating a new repository and loose my git history, but would love to find out what is happening here.

Comment: The files in folder1 were originally created on a linux server and download to a windows computer the files in folder2 were then created on the windows computer. I have now downloaded the files within a github repository to my new macbook and now this error occurs. There must be something to do with the encoding of the filenames that is not visible.

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea what is causing this error! However it is not being caused by anything to do with coming from windows. Some of the files are being downloaded from my server using Cyberduck, there seems to be a problem with how the filenames are being saved (that is not visible to me in node, terminal or in finder!). I am now just going to use scp command instead of cyberduck for this tastk.